# How can I re-run a node.js script as soon as it is completed?

Tags: node.js

I have a worker.js script that takes a **variable** amount of time to complete. As soon as it is finished running, I would like to restart it immediately.

One option is to use a cron job and a lock file to prevent multiple instances of the script from running. However, there must be a cleaner way to re-run worker.js as soon as it is completed?

Comment: What are you running it from?  From another node.js script?  From a bash file?

Comment: @jfriend00 I am running it on a worker dyno on heroku. It's just a single file that I currently call through the command line

Comment: Well, you need some sort of script that runs it again when it completes.  Bash, Javascript, etc...  Not sure what type of magic solution you're expecting.

Comment: why don't you make a script that executes forever? since that seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do this using [forever-monitor](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever-monitor). As soon as the process exits at a variable time, forever simply restarts it programatically